# why does digest and digest('hex') result in different outputs?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, sha256, cryptojs

I have 2 piece of codes.

```js
1ST ONE
const hash1 = (data) => createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('hex');
var a1 = hash1("A");
var b1 = hash1("B");
console.log(hash1(a1+b1));

2ND ONE
const hash2 = (data) => createHash('sha256').update(data).digest();
var a2 = hash2("A");
var b2 = hash2("B");
console.log(hash2(Buffer.concat([a2,b2])).toString('hex'));
```

Why do they print the different results ?

`digest('hex')` and `digest()` are the same , but in different kind of format, but still the same. So, why do I get different results in console ?  is it the + operator when I sum up the hexes versus when i sum up buffers ? why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default encoding for `hash.digest([encoding])` is `utf-8`. `utf-8` is a variable-length encoding system. It will only use as many bytes as necessary to represent each character (anywhere between 1-4 bytes).

However, when you specify `hex` as the encoding, each character is stored as *exactly* 2 hexadecimal characters.

When you call `hash.toString('hex')` on a `utf-8` encoded hash, the resulting hex representation is equivalent to hashing with `hex` encoding in the first place (as in `hash.digest('hex')`).

So, even though the `hex` representation is the same in each case, the actual ***data*** is different. i.e.:

`hash.digest() != hash.digest('hex')`, but

`hash.digest().toString('hex') == hash.digest('hex')`.

Answer (score 1):

`digest('hex')` and `digest()` technically different

Please try this code

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

const hash1 = (data) => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('hex');
var a1 = hash1("A");
var b1 = hash1("B");

//console.log(a1)
//console.log(b1)


console.log(hash1(a1+b1));

const hash2 = (data) => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest();

var a2 = hash2("A");
var b2 = hash2("B");
//console.log(a2.toString("hex"))
//console.log(b2.toString("hex"))

console.log(hash2(a2.toString("hex") + b2.toString("hex") ).toString("hex"));
```

In the first you are appending two `hex` string and passing to `hash1`
In the second you are appending two non hex string and passing to `hash2`

[Run Nodejs online](https://repl.it/@dickensas/crptoexample1#index.js)

Comment: yes, in the second i append 2 non hex string, but instead i append 2 buffers, but the thing is buffer is the same as hex, it's just in a different format. isn't that right ?

Comment: No, buffer is the buffer of the original UTF-8 content, when you print in console.log it shows the hex values, which means `digest('hex')` and `digest()` technically different